# Circular arrangement problem

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have one question of circular round table arrangement:
" How to find the number of ways in which 6 persons out of 5 men and 5 women can be seated at around table such that 2 men are never together.

I am confused when the condition has been applied. Please help..